# Vectorize for loop

Tags: matlab

The loop is as follows:

```
for j = 1:20   
  sigma = (y<0) - (y>=0);    
  x0 = x;  
  out_angle = out_angle - sigma*lut(j);  
  x = x-(y.*sigma)*poweroftwo;  
  y = y+(x0.*sigma)*poweroftwo;   
  poweroftwo = poweroftwo/2;  
end
```

out_angle, x,y and sigma are matrices of dim m*n. lut is an array of size 20. poweroftwo is a scalar with initial value 1. Is it possible to vectorize this code and avoid the for loop?

Comment: I assume `m` and/or `n` are very large, or that the `20` is an example value which is really much larger for your problem? Because if that isn't so, a vectorization of this tiny loop makes little sense, and will in all probability be slower than the loop (see [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/news_notes/may03/profiler.html) for example)

Comment: Yes, m and n are pretty large. Infact, there is no limit on their values. The code is designed so as to work for any value of m and n. Because of the interdependancies between the matrices x,y and sigma, I'm finding it extremely difficult to vectorize this. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you profile this? It doesn't seem like it should be slow...Are you positive this is your bottleneck?

Comment: Actually, it is not a matter of whether it is slow or fast. This is an assignment given to me and it was specifically mentioned to avoid for loops. Also, now that I have worked on it for quite a long time, I would like to know whether vectorization is possible for this problem, even if it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of informaiton is missing for the vectorization of this loop. Just have a look at the line

```
out_angle = out_angle - sigma*lut(j);
```

After vectorization you would like to have an expression similar to

```
out_angle(j) = out_angle(j-1) - sigma*lut(j);
```

You immediately see that the current `out_angle` depends on the previously computed value. This also means that `out_angle` can only be computed sequentially **except** if you can
come up with an explicit representation of `out_angle`.

```
out_angle(j) = out_angle(j-1) - sigma*lut(j)
             = out_angle(j-2) - sigma*lut(j-1) - sigma*lut(j)
             = out_angle(j-3) - sigma*lut(j-2) - sigma*lut(j-1) - sigma*lut(j)
             = ...
             = out_angle(0) - sum_{k = 0}^j (sigma*lut(k))
```

The thing gets more complicated as `sigma` also depends on `j`, i.e. actually you have
`sigma(j)` and thus

```
out_angle(j) = out_angle(0) - sum_{k = 0}^j (sigma(k)*lut(k))
```

Unfortunately you also have only an implicit expression for `sigma` which you have to
resolve in the same manner. You can probably think a bit about the structure behind `sigma`. This is a variable, which is 1, where `y` is negative and -1 where `y` is positive
or zero, i.e. it is something like

```
sigma = -mySign(y)
```

where `mySign` acts like the `sign` function but gives 1 for a zero argument.

If you can find an explicit representation for `sigma`, you can insert it into the explicit representation of `out_angle` above. After that you can (most likely) vectorize the code.

Comment: But even if I find such an expression, the problems doesnt end. The value of x depends on the previously computed value of y, which inturn depends on the previous value of x. Is there any way to counter this or is it safe to assume that vectorization is simply not possible in this case?

Comment: You can of course apply the same approach to the `x` variable as well even if it depends on the previous `y` value. The question is what you know about `x(0)` and `y(0)`. Is this random or measured data? In this case vectorization is not possible. If this data is static, you can probably vectorize the code. However, the effort seems to be quite big. Finally it is also questionable, if you have enough memory. Right now you need to store `x`, `y`, `sigma` and `out_data` only once. After vectorization you have 20 copies of them.